# Change theme on Fragment change

Tags: java, android, fragment, themes

I need to change `fragment` theme dynamically, i try this code but it not work on `onCreate` or `onCreateView()`

```
getActivity().setTheme(R.style.ActionMode);
```

How i can set theme from `fragment`?

Answer (score 3):

In the `onCreateView()` method, you have to create `ContextThemeWrapper` and inflate style of theme from it, like below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    Context context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.your_Custom_Theme);
    //clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(context);
    //inflate using the cloned inflater, not the passed in default
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, i try this code, but it not work for me

Comment: May i know what kind of issue you're facing, lets share your code. So that we can help you to resolve.